# How do you communicate with the main page from a HTML notification?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webkit

I'm working on a fork of an online Twitter client. ([Streamie](http://streamie.org), if you're interested.) I'd like to improve the Chrome notifications by using HTML notifications instead of the static ones it uses now.

The problem is that I need to get the tweet object from the main page to the notification, and I'm not sure how to do this. In my Chrome extension I got around this by making an array with a queue of tweets to show, adding a function to the window object which returned queue.shift() and then calling that function via `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().dequeueMsg();`.

However, I obviously don't have this option in a web client. Is there any way to communicate from a notification with the window that opened it, or from the page to the notification's DOM?

Comment: What do you mean by "HTML notification"?

Comment: @Pointy `window.webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification("http://link/to/page.html")`

Comment: wow, learn something every day :-)  Thanks

Comment: Can't help with your problem. But love the app, using it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well from the spec:

> Within a web notification, the `window.opener` property should be set to the window which created the notification. If the notification was created by a worker script, `window.opener` should be `null`.

It looks like code in the notification page can access `window.opener` just like a page created with `window.open()` can. (Now, as to the practical aspect of doing this with today's actual browsers, that's another thing I guess.)

Comment: That's what I thought, and I've been trying that, but every time I do the window.opener property is null.

Comment: Hmm well maybe this is something that browsers don't yet support properly. Or, is it possible that your notification URL is not in the same domain as the other page?